# За что отвечают файлы в папке с exe-файлом проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я написал небольшое приложение на C# в Visual Studio 2012. В папке Debug(и Release) помимо Exe-файла для запуска приложения, и сопутствующих файлов и папок, которые я сам создал(папка Log, Settings) для работы приложения, имеются другие файлы(.config, vshost.exe.config и т.д.).

Вопрос: для чего нужны эти файлы? Если их удалить, будет ли приложение запускать по нажатию на exe-файл, и будет ли оно корректно работать?[image: содержимое папки Debug]

Comment: Если вы хотите свою программу отдавать другим людям, то, конечно, в таком виде это делать не следует. Нужно использовать специальные инструменты для создания установочного пакета. Например, правый клик по названию проекта -> Publish (не знаю как эта команда будет в русской версии VS) и будет вызвана утилита для создания установочного пакета на основе вашего проекта.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Файлы `*.vshost.*` нужны для Visual Studio. Они грузятся отладчиком C# (и наверное VB) и постоянно находятся в памяти, и когда вы запускаете процесс на отладку, он грузится в контексте vshost-процесса. Таким образом ускоряется старт отладки, также в контексте этого процесса производятся вычисления в Immediate Window. Эти файлы должны быть в том же каталоге, что и приложение, т. к. иначе будут проблемы с загрузкой зависимых модулей, да и запрос каталога программы даст неверный результат. (Ещё немного про vshost [тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dtemp/2004/08/17/vshost-the-hosting-process/).)
2. Файлы `*.pdb` содержат просто отладочную информацию, такую как имена локальных переменных и номера строк. Они нужны, чтобы отладчик мог сопоставить скомпилированный код исходному тексту.
3. Файлы `*.manifest` представляют собой [манифест сборки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1w45z383(v=vs.110).aspx). Он может быть включён в `.exe` или лежать рядом с файлом. Для `.exe`- файла манифест включается в него при компиляции, чтобы не создавать лишних файлов. Но для `.vshost`-файла он лежит рядом, чтобы не нужно было перекомпилировать `.vshost`, то есть, для оптимизации.
4. Файлы `*.config` представляют собой содержимое `App.config` вашего приложения. Там хранятся установки уровня приложения. При инсталляции приложения этот файл должен быть скопирован в каталог инсталляции (в Program Files). Пользовательские установки хранятся в `%APPDATA%` текущего пользователя и создаются автоматически.

---

Эти файлы не нужно удалять, но если вы удалите, они всё равно будут пересозданы компилятором. Для деплоймента вам нужен только `.exe` (и/или `.dll`), и `.config` (тот, который не от vshost). Ещё можно сохранить для себя .pdb для будущей отладки, но в поставку клиентам включать его не нужно. (Если вы собираете версию для отладки, тогда пригодится.)

Comment: хм... а по-подробней про *.vshost можно? А именно, почему будет неправильно определяться каталог приложения, как это связано? разумеется для релизной сборки, с отладочной понятно, что нужно все

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, многие приложения ищут ресурсы в каталоге, где лежит главная сборка. Если `.vshost` будет лежать в другом месте, то `Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` даст каталог, в котором лежит `.vshost`, а не скомпилированная программа. А это как бы популярный паттерн.

Comment: А если я делаю сборку не из  студии, а ручной компиляцией например? Когда-то давно баловался таким чтобы разбить сборку на модули и обновлять классы независимо без необходимости пересобирать все, и вроде без проблем работало даже без этих файлов

Comment: @rdorn: Конечно, тогда они не нужны. Это файлы лишь для отладчика Visual Studio.

Comment: спасибо, а то я уж подумал что у меня крыша поехала =)

Comment: @VladD, в вашем ответе не хватает информации о том будет ли работать приложение, если удалить эти файлы.

Comment: Тогда уж не только будут ли работать, а что конкретно перестанет работать. pdb насколько помню помогает в отладке плюс в стектрейсе при падении указывает конкретные строчки. app.config - настройки приложения, которые обычно не критичны и можно удалять, если их не редактировали при разработке вручную =)

Comment: Добавил, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, то есть, если мне надо взять мое приложение, перенести и запускать для его работы на другой машине(на которой нет VS) - мне нужно оставить только ,exe, .config, ну и мои файлы, которые для работы создал?

Comment: @lcnw в некоторых случаях, можно обойтись и без .config

Comment: @lcnw: Ну и если в каталог скопировались dll-ки, то и их тоже. В некоторых случаях можно обойтись без .config, но чтобы не думать, надо или нет, лучше взять с собой.